# Error: can not read options configuration file config.ini from nodeos

Tags: nodeos, keosd, eosio.system, single-node

After installing EOSIO, when starting nodeos & keosd, I get the error:

```
/mnt/d/EOS_setupo/eos/build/programs/keosd$ keosd

Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::reading_file> >
std::exception::what: can not read options configuration file '/home/chinmay/eosio-wallet/config.ini'

$ cd ..
$ cd nodeos/
$ nodeos

Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::reading_file> >
std::exception::what: can not read options configuration file '/home/chinmay/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini'
```

I am running on Ubuntu.
Initially I am able to run nodeos but after sometime I get this error.
I tried to build it again and install again but this did not help.

Comment: Hey chinmay, welcome to EOSIO stack exchange. In future can you please copy and paste the error messages into the question instead of sending screenshots? Thanks in advance. On the topic of your question, what steps did you take to install eosio? Which version of eosio are you running on your computer?

Comment: Hello,
Will update error posting way.
I follow below steps to installation of EOSIO:
Version : 1.7.4
1. installed ubuntu subsystem on windows 10.
2. sudo apt install cmake
3. sudo apt install git
4. git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eos --recursive
5. cd eos/script ./eosio_build.sh ubuntu full
6. cd eos/script ./eosio_install.sh

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If not can you paste the contents of `/home/chinmay/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini`?